# How would I create a array using months then use a switch statement to display current months

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, switch-statement

I'm wanting to create an array that will store the months of the year like this.I want to alse be able to call this in a div like

```
 var months = new Array["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

then create a switch statement that will get the current month and display it from that similar to this.

```
switch(num)
  {
    case 0:
      month="January";
      break;
    case 1:
      month="February";
      break;
    case 2:
      month="March";
      break;
    case 3:
      month="April";
      break;
    case 4:
      month="May";
      break;
    case 5:
      month="June";
      break;
    case 6:
      month="July";
      break;
    case 7:
      month="August";
      break;
    case 8:
      month="September";
      break;
    case 9:
      month="October";
      break;
    case 10:
      month="November";
      break;
    case 11:
      month="December";
      break;
```

How would I call that in my HTML page? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: put them inside function, pass `num` as argument and return the month at the end of function

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the array.

```
function getMonth(num){
    return months[num] || "month not found";
}

getMonth(0); //January

getMonth(1);//February

getMonth(12);//month not found, since the array counts start from 0.
```

I'm not sure what you are wanting, but here is html code with various ways of looking up the month name. jQuery would have made some of the operations more cross-browser friendly, but you didn't list jQuery so I did this in pure javascript.

```
<body>
    <select id='allMonths'></select><br/><br/>
    <input id='txtMonth' type='text' value='1'/><br/>
    <p id='monthName'>Click button below to change based on text box value</p>
    <a href='' onclick='event.preventDefault(); changeMonth();'>Click me to change month based on text box value</a><br/><br/>
    <div id='allMonthsListed'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            allMonths = document.getElementById('allMonths'),
            txtMonth = document.getElementById('txtMonth'),
            monthName = document.getElementById('monthName'),
            allMonthsListed = document.getElementById('allMonthsListed');
        function getMonth(num){
            return months[num] || "month not found";
        }
        for(var idx = 0; idx < months.length;idx++){
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.innerText = months[idx];
            allMonths.appendChild(option);
        }
        function changeMonth(){
            var month = txtMonth.value;
            if(/^\d+$/.test(month)){
                monthName.innerText = getMonth(parseInt(month) + 1);
            }else{
                monthName.innerText = "Must enter number";
            }
        }

        for(var idx = 0; idx < months.length;idx++){
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.innerText = months[idx];
            allMonthsListed.appendChild(p);
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm still rather confused on how this works. Let's say I would like to put that function inside a div like <div class="month"</div> I was trying to do something like var month = getmonth(num);
document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = month(); It doesnt seem to be working when I do that though.

Comment: Can you post what you want the html to do.  Then I can update the Javascript to do that.  Html by itself can't interact with the array or Javascript.  It's javascripts job to interact with the html.

Comment: I just want the HTML to display what month it is.

Comment: @Nathan Rivera, Do you want a select box, text box, our just display all the months on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Hi no need to create switch statment very simple

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var d = new Date();
console.log(monthNames[d.getMonth()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Two files:

Your javascript method.

```
methods.js

var months =  ["January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"];

function monthsOfYear() {

    var num = document.getElementById('numberMonth').value;

    document.getElementById('nameOfMonth').innerHTML = months[num];
}
```

and the html page

```
page.html

<div>
    <input type="text" id="numberMonth">
    <button onclick="monthsOfYear()">Click</button>
</div>

//will show the name of the month chosen
<div id='nameOfMonth'></div>

//import the javascript file
<script src='methods.js'></script>
```

This is the basic way to do this.
Since the arrays start count from 0, the number 12 will got undefined, so you need to solve this.
You could use jquery or angularjs to improve your work.
I hope the helps.

Comment: you said that the declaration of the array isn't good but then you assign it twice.  you first assign it as an empty array ("new Array();") and then again as '["January", ...."December"]'.